# HTML to WORDPRESS

Tags: theme-development, css, html, design

I am very very new at this but would like to expand my creativity.

I would like to design/build my own wordpress. Because this is a huge task I have read that first designing the page with just html and css THEN bringing it into wordpress is a better a solution. Would you say this to be true?

Comment: Please read the help center pages, specifically [what types of questions are not appropriate here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Your question is primarily opinion-based, so is not a good fit for the site's format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Designing in plain 'ol HTML and CSS *could* make easier.  However, there are many features of the WordPress framework that you'll miss out on.  Read some of the WP documentation in the Codex to begin with:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Site_Design_and_Layout

I will also draw your attention to the body class attribute, which I find extremely useful when designing my WordPress CSS.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class

Good Luck, and have fun!